# Why is my array declared as an array of references

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Today, while compiling some code with GCC 4.9.2 for the first time, I encountered a strange error about an array being interpreted as an array of references.

I was able to reproduce the error with a quick example. Why is the constructor of `Link` interpreting `buses` as an array of references in the constructor of `Stuff`.

The following code works with MSVC10 and ICC 11.1

```
#include <iostream>

struct Bus
{
    Bus(std::string n) : name(n) {}
    std::string name;
};

template<typename T>
class Link
{
public:
    Link(const T* i)
    {
        data = (T*)i;   
    }

    const T* get() const
    {
        return data;
    }
private:
    T* data = nullptr;  
};

class Stuff
{
public:
    Stuff(Link<Bus> l_b) : link(l_b) {}
private:
    Link<Bus> link;
};

void print(Link<Bus> l)
{
    std::cout << l.get()->name << '\n';   
}

int main(void) {
    Bus buses[4] = { Bus("0"), Bus("1"), Bus("2"), Bus("3") };

    print(Link<Bus>(&buses[0]));

    Stuff s(Link<Bus>(&buses[0]));    

    return 0;
}
```

But with GCC and Clang, this gives an error :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:44:32: error: declaration of 'buses' as array of references

     Stuff s(Link<Bus>(&buses[0]));
```

Yet, the call to the `print` function works as intended. I am clueless about why the constructor fails.

I found a solution to that problem, by calling buses lik that in the call to the constructor of `Stuff`

```
Stuff s(Link<Bus>((&buses)[0]));
```

But I'm really interested to know why it fails.

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e52bb74e90f8fdf8)

Comment: Looks like the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: If I rewrite your declaration as `Stuff s(Link<Bus>& buses[0])`, does it make more sense?

Comment: Does this work... `Stuff s{Link<Bus>(&buses[0])};` ...?

Comment: Or `Stuff s = Stuff(Link<Bus>(&buses[0]));`.

Comment: @Angew its is still not working with a recent GCC https://wandbox.org/permlink/goDtz3TABvmswhCJ

Comment: @Eljay @bipll `Stuff s(Link<Bus>{&buses[0]});` works too

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne MVP is not a bug, it's a characteristic of the language. Which means the compiler is *correct.* It's one of the reasons `{}` was introduced as universal initialisation.

Comment: @Angew: It's not a compiler bug, but it's not outrageous to suggest that it's a bug in the design of the language. Albeit, yes, one that is known and acknowledged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are the victim of the [Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/1870760) rule.

The compiler sees:

```
Stuff s(Link<Bus>((&buses)[0]));
```

As a function declaration of a function named `s` that returns a `Stuff` object and asks for an 0-element array of `Link` object references.

To fix this and tell the compiler you're actually trying to create a `Stuff` object you should use the `{}` syntax to avoid ambiguity:

```
Stuff s{ Link<Bus>((&buses)[0]) };
```

Comment: Is it the same thing if I call `Stuff s(Link<Bus>{&buses[0]});` ?

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne Yes, since that no longer can be a function declaration.

Comment: Now my old MSVC fails with the fix. Awesome. Thanks for your explication.

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne this syntax has been Standard C++ since 2011 and has been accepted by Visual Studio since VS2013.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'll put a note for when we upgrade then *sigh*

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne If you need this to work with pre C++11 MSVC, surround the  constructor argument with parens. That should also work. I.e `Stuff s((Link<Bus>(&buses[0])));`

Comment: Finally a Q&A mentioning the most-vexing parse which is _actually_ about the most-vexing parse :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know, right? I've lost count of how many basic function decls have been misbranded with mvp nomenclature on this site. It's nice to actually see a *real* one.